# Is there any way to store varibles across devices in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

As the title says, it is possible to have the state of a variable embedded in the notebook file, so when it's shared with another person in another device that variable can be retrieved later?

Something like:

```
NotebookFile.ipynb
{
  "nbformat": 4,
  "metadata": {
    "kernelspec": {
      "name": "python3",
      "display_name": "Python 3"
    }
    "stored": {
      "my_string": "Hello world!"
      "result":    "6.67e-11"
    }
...
```

*That was just an example, nothing too serious but you get the point*

I know there is the magic command `%store` but that only works inside your local machine by pickle the variable and saving it in a file

Comment: What content do you plan to store?

Comment: For my project I wanted to store lists and other iterables